# Implememting autolookup in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json object in my hand, and three textbox in a row. when I enter something on first textbox, and if it matches any data I have in my object I want to fill the remaining two textboxes with the corresponding row. I want only one row data to be shown, most matching row I have in my search result rest can be ignored. I have tried many ways to achieve this but all failed.
My HTML is like this

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="friendObj in friends  | filter:search:strict  | limitTo:1">
            <input ng-model="search.name" />
            <input ng-model="friendObj.name" />
            <input ng-model="friendObj.phone" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

**Note** : I won't be able to change My HTML structure at any condition.

```
My JS Code


    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.friends = [{
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1276'
    }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
    }, {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321'
    }, {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }, {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765'
    }, {
        name: 'Juliette',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }];

}]);
```

I don't think I have reached anywhere at my objective. I am confused is ng-repeat and filter itself is the right tools for this job? Can any one point out the correct way to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/v2xqmkwx/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dLhe11ke/1/)

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
        <input ng-model="searchTerm" ng-change="search()" />
        <input ng-model="friends[currentRowIndex].name" />
        <input ng-model="friends[currentRowIndex].phone" />
    </div>
    <div></div>
</body>


angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.friends = [{
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1276'
    }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
    }, {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321'
    }, {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }, {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765'
    }, {
        name: 'Juliette',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }];

    $scope.searchTerm = "";
    $scope.currentRowIndex = -1;
    $scope.search = function () {

        for (var i in $scope.friends) {
            if ($scope.friends[i].name.indexOf($scope.searchTerm) > -1 || $scope.friends[i].phone.indexOf($scope.searchTerm) > -1) {
                $scope.currentRowIndex = i;
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}]);
```

Comment: Type 'Ju' in first textbox show name: 'Julie', phone: '555-8765'. Case sensitive.